# Using ClearUsernameBinding without App.Config

Tags: wcf, web-services, c#-4.0

I have successfully used CUB to call a web service but I depend on the configuration in app.config. I wonder if it is possible to generate the binding by code without adding any entries to the app.config.

I have tried the following:

```
ClearUsernameBinding binding = new ClearUsernameBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8087/SampleService/");

EchoServiceReference.EchoServiceClient client = new EchoServiceReference.EchoServiceClient(binding, address);
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "yaron";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "1234";
Console.WriteLine(client.EchoString("hi"));
```

but I got the error:

```
Envelope Version 'EnvelopeNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none)' does not support adding Message Headers.
```

Comment: if instead of ClearUsernameBinding you use BasicHttpBinding do you get the same error?

Comment: If I try BasicHttpBinding created by code, I get "Content Type text/xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:8087/SampleService/.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched." I am trying to connect to the TestService that you include in your CUB solution. Creating CUB based on app.config works fine but creating CUB by code fails with the error I posted in the question. What is the difference? What part of app.config I need to add by code?

Comment: please send me a sample sln which reproduce the problem. you just need the client code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create the binding add this code:

```
binding.SetMessageVersion(System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion.Soap11);
```

Comment: Thanks worked but with binding.SetMessageVersion(System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion.Soap12);